# Formatting a single field to display a button based on a choice fields value using JSON

Tags: json, sharepoint-online

I have a field that defines the document being approved. Field Name is "WorkflowRequired", which is a choice field.
I would like to display a button based on that choice.
I can do this singularly but when I attempt to incorporate multiple if statements, the logic fails.

This is what I have.
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",

If([@WorkflowRequired]=='DI Exit',
"elmType": "button",
"txtContent": "Launch DI Exit",
"customRowAction": {
"action": "executeFlow",
"actionParams": "{"id": "86b2de78-e44c-4e6d-9707-08369f679a42"}"
},
"style": {
"background-color": "#0080ff",
"color": "white",
"border-radius": "0 15px",
"visibility": "=if(([$DIExitApprovalStatus] == 'Pending'),'visible','hidden')"
}

If([@WorkflowRequired]=='OA Exit',
"elmType": "button",
"txtContent": "Launch OA Exit",
"customRowAction": {
"action": "executeFlow",
"actionParams": "{"id": "e7879e07-2fed-4cee-9a13-9aa4fc673b3c"}"
},
"style": {
"background-color": "#008082",
"color": "white",
"border-radius": "0 15px",
"visibility": "=if(([$OAExitApprovalStatus] == 'Pending'),'visible','hidden')")
}

If([@WorkflowRequired]=='CD_CV Exit',
"elmType": "button",
"txtContent": "Launch CD_CV Exit",
"customRowAction": {
"action": "executeFlow",
"actionParams": "{"id": "52999e98-ea2b-46c7-ab21-d5e8e727fa94"}"
},
"style": {
"background-color": "#008082",
"color": "white",
"border-radius": "0 15px",
"visibility": "=if(([$_CD_CVExitApprovalStatus] == 'Pending'),'visible','hidden')"
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, if you want to apply the if condition, you will need to place it after the properties. It is just like `"elmType": "button", "txtContent":"=IF()"`

You can see the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#conditional-formatting-based-on-a-number-range-basic)

A [blog](https://thechriskent.com/2019/03/20/conditionally-launch-flows-using-list-formatting/) having a similar scenario with you.